# Give an example of a continuous non-Lipschitz function.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Give an example of a continuous non-Lipschitz function. Check only the non-Lipschitz condition using negation.

I know that $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ at $[0,1]$ is non-Lipschitz and is continuous at $[0,1]$. I got the proof by contradiction but I want to prove it by the negation of being Lipschitz.

$f$ is not Lipschitz at $[0, 1]$ if $\forall N >0, \exists  x_1, x_2\in [0, 1]$, $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|>N |x_1-x_2|$

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Shouldn't that "si" be an "if"? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} \to +\infty$ when $x\to 0^+$. Thus for any $N>0$, $\exists \ x_N\in (0,1]$ such that $\frac{\sqrt{x_N}}{x_N} > N$. Follows that $|f(x_N)-f(0)|>N \cdot |x_N-0|$